# Add an object to a java structure only if it isn't already there

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an arrayList that I want to add to, as long as the value isn't already stored in it. For example if my array is like this:

```
H
LK
KL
LS
```

And I have the value LS, it wouldn't be added. But if the value was A, it would be. I don't care about order or sorting. Just whether or not the information is in there.

I was thinking that the code should look something like this:

```
value = A;
no = 0; 
for (int o; arraylist.length; o++)
   if (arraylist.get(o).equals(value)){
     continue;
   }else{ 
      no++;
   }
}
if (arraylist.length = no){
    arraylist.add(value);
}
```

But there has to be an easier way to do it.
Does anyone know a more concise way to do this?

Comment: You need a `HashSet` here.

Comment: `ArrayList` has the method `contains()`. Consider using it.

Comment: Do you have to use an `ArrayList`, or would a `LinkedHashSet` (which preserves insertion order like a list) work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would consider using a `Set` instead of an ArrayList. Sets are defined by their requirement that all objects be unique. A `HashSet` is a good default choice and might be the more correct data structure for you to use in this case, but that is ultimately your call.

When you add to a set, the `add` method will return `false` if the object is already contained in the set, and a duplicate will not be added.

If you need predictable iteration order, you could use the LinkedHashSet.

> This implementation differs from HashSet in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is the order in which elements were inserted into the set (insertion-order)

Finally, you could consider using a navigable set in TreeSet. It doesn't look sorting is important based on the information above, so it's probably not the right choice for you, but it's good information to have in your back pocket.

Just make sure that if you are adding your own class's objects to a Set, that you override, and override properly, the equals() method. Not doing so will cause only references to be compared and will lead to unexpected behavior, and a notable headache. Use the @Override annotation to make sure you're overriding properly, but I digress.

[HashSet Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)

[TreeSet Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)

[LinkedHashSet Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html)

Comment: Having the data sorted isn't important to me, but I always look forward to learning. I will definitely be sure to check it out. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Use `ArrayList#contains` instead:

```
if (!arraylist.contains(value)){
     arraylist.add(value);
}
```

Note that `contains` depends on your objects having an `equals()` method. Namely, either the list contains null and `value` is null, or `value.equals(o)` for some `o` that is an element of the list.

Answer (score 3):

One clean way to do it, if you don't mind the performance hit because of copying and ordering isn't important:

Use a `HashSet`, insert everything in it and the copy its contents into a `List`. Example:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();

set.add("H");
set.add("LK");
set.add("KL");
set.add("LS");
set.add("LS");
set.add("A");

List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.addAll(set);

System.out.println(list);
```

Output:

```
[A, KL, LK, LS, H]
```

Comment: Using `LinkedHashSet` instead of `HashSet` should help solving the 'ordering' part of the drawback given by this method

Answer (score 2):

If you need `List` semantics (i.e. elements are ordered), then you could subclass `ArrayList` (you'd call it `UniqueArrayList` or something) and override its `add` method to call `contains` and add the element only if it doesn't exist.

```
public class UniqueArrayList<E> extends ArrayList<E> {

    @Override
    public boolean add(E e) {
        if (!contains(e)) {
            return super.add(e);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // TODO: override addAll etc.
}
```

This would be the most object-oriented way, compared to having `if(!list.contains(...` checks (or even loops) everywhere you need this.

It would also allow you to keep the existing functionality of the `List` objects, for instance accessing elements by index via `get`, in case this is a requirement.

If the concept of order is not important, you could use a `Set`. Sets, both by definition and implementation, contain only unique elements.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have wrong data structure. Set will be better in this case.